# Access request parameters from a JSP View in Spring Web MVC without putting them in a model

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'd like to be able to access *some* HTTP GET parameters directly in a JSP, *without* having to pass them through a Controller+Model, but at the same time still use the dispatcher/controller/model/view mechanism for other parameters and logic.

This is because I have many HTTP GET parameters that are generated by Javascript and used also only in Javascript. My Controllers don't need them at all.

I tried `${arg}`, `${request.arg}`, `${requestScope.arg}`, nothing seems to work.

If I bypass the dispatcher, `${requestScope.arg}` works.

But is there a way to make it work *with the dispatcher*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If that's request parameters that you want to access (and not request attributes like the title says), then the syntax is `${param.parameterName}`.

If it's request attributes, then it's `${requestScope.attributeName}`.

See http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref207.html#1010522 for a quick reference.